# Angularjs : Dynamically created tab does not get active/selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have the below angularjs code which creates tabs by pressing the new button. But the newly created tab does not get active or selected after creation. Always the one before the last one get active ! 
Anyone knows what is wrong?

plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/1329tgGonObRQ6Drk75A?p=preview

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
         <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsParentController">


   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
               Sure to delete?
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>


    <uib-tabset active="active">

        <uib-tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             heading="{{workspace.name}}"
             >
            <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
                <div>
                    {{$parent.workspace.id}} : {{ $parent.workspace.name}}
                </div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
                 <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="open('sm',workspace)">Delete</button>
            </div>     
        </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="0" select="addWorkspace()">
              <uib-tab-heading>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </uib-tab-heading>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("TabsParentController", function ($scope,$uibModal) {
  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size, workspace) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {

         workspace: function () {
          return workspace;
        }

      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
       var index=$scope.workspaces.indexOf(selectedItem)
      $scope.workspaces.splice(index,1);     
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };



    var setAllInactive = function() {
         //angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
           // workspace.active = false;
   // });
    };
    var addNewWorkspace = function() {

        var id = $scope.workspaces.length+1 ;

        $scope.workspaces.push({
            id: id,

            name: "Workspace " + id,

        });
        $scope.active=$scope.workspaces.length -1;


    };

    $scope.workspaces =
    [

    ];

    $scope.addWorkspace = function () {
        setAllInactive();
        addNewWorkspace();

    };    


     $scope.remove=function(item){ 
      var index=$scope.workspaces.indexOf(item)
      $scope.workspaces.splice(index,1);     
    }

});

angular.module('plunker').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, workspace) {

  $scope.selectedworkspace = workspace;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close( $scope.selectedworkspace );
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});




app.controller ("TabsChildController", function($scope, $log){

});
```

Comment: How does this `uib-tabset active="active"` work? It seems like a directive, but I can't seem to find any directive definition in your code.

Comment: @emil.c its angularjs bootstrap tag, imported by : //angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js

Comment: So how does it work?

Comment: @emil.c you import the JS library into  html and use the directives to create controls, you can read more here:  : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I know how you can import modules and use their directives, the question is how this particular directive works, how does it select the tab?

Comment: @emil.c by setting the the 'active' setting. active gets the index of the active tab. I set the active in my JS code .

Comment: Well, you now have the answer :)

Comment: @emil.c I tried having buttons that set the active and that way works (I am think you are missing something). The problem is setting the active from a function in my JS. As the below answer suggests, seems the problem is in delay of creating new workspace ...so at the time setting there is no new tab yet.

Comment: I have indeed missed something because I haven't really understood the problem in depth. The answer is totally correct so sorry for misleading with my questions.

Comment: @emil.c oh no need to be sorry , thanks for trying to help. appreciate it.

Comment: By the way, looking at your $scope.remove function, you could just .pop() the element from the array like so `$scope.workspaces` without splicing it and getting the index.

Comment: @emil.c thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to the newest tab as active, you will want to set the

```
$scope.active = $scope.workspaces.length;
```

but the other problem is that, when you push a new workspace. it takes a bit of time for the directive to re-render the DOM and get all the scope variables ready. therefore right after push, if you attempt to assign the newest tab as active will result in error.

So, to quickly prove my point (no the most correct way), try this and your code to will work. Remember to inject $timeout as a dependency

```
app.controller("TabsParentController", 
    function ($scope,$uibModal, $timeout) {


        ....
        ....

        $scope.workspaces.push({
            id: id,
            name: "Workspace " + id,
        });

        //introduce a 50 ms delay before setting the active tab
        $timeout(function(){
           $scope.active = $scope.workspaces.length;
        }, 50);

        ....
        ....

    }
);
```

[see it in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/adtFP9uN1l5blXp3taxW?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes seems you are right. Is there a way to create a function that sets the active tab after successful completion of AddNewTab function? I am looking for something similar get.then or get or success which can call a function after successful completion of get ! is there such a thing for functions?

Comment: @user3033921 when i first looked at your problem. I had the exact same question as emily.c. If you can wait for the directive to be ready then set the active, it would be most ideal. For that part you will probably need to look up the documentation yourself. My answer was a prove of concept that there is a bit of churning that you need to wait for. Cheers

Comment: @user3033921 I have a feeling that your code is a modified version of OdeToCode's example. My gut feeling is telling me that the current set up does have some collision with the angular module you are importing, and it doesn't seem right. You should find some better examples of how to programmatically set tabs. I have not been using the angular version of bootstrap, and i can tell you there are many competitive alternatives out there. I would suggest Angular Material.

Comment: @ji_incoding thanks. I will look into this. I am new to angularjs